# How to run "SYLT Editor" after installation?

Tags: software-installation, subtitle

After installing [SYLT Editor](http://www.compuphase.com/software_sylteditor.htm) by running its package file, I can't seem to run it from anywhere. It's neither been added to the start menu, nor is it possible to run it from command line. Where can I find it?

p.s.
content of typescript:

> Script started on Sun 16 Aug 2015 04:23:49 PM IRDT
>   [01;32mmeysam@meysam-pc[01;34m
>   /media/meysam/Data/Software/Media/LyricsEditor $[00m ./SYLT\ Editor\
>   1.1.5108.package
>
> rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop':
>   No such file or directory rm: cannot remove
>   '/media/meysam/Data/Software/Media/LyricsEditor/autopackage.2818912610/meta/@compuphase.com/sylteditor:1.1.5108':
>   Directory not empty [01;32mmeysam@meysam-pc[01;34m
>   /media/meysam/Data/Software/Media/LyricsEditor $[00m  Script done on
>   Sun 16 Aug 2015 04:25:27 PM IRDT

And the final window:
[image]

The content of `/usr/local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=Apkg-Verify;Apkg-Remove;
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio;X-Red-Hat-Base;
Comment=A utility to create or modify SYLT frames in MP3 tracks, for synchronized lyrics or text.
Exec=/opt/sylteditor/bin/sylteditor
GenericName=SYLT Editor
Icon=syltedit32
MimeType=text/plain;
Name=SYLT Editor
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TryExec=/opt/sylteditor/bin/sylteditor
Type=Application
Version=1.1
X-Autopackage=@compuphase.com/sylteditor:1.1.5108

[Desktop Action Apkg-Verify]
Exec=package verify sylteditor
Icon=package
Name=Verify Package
Name[de]=Validieren Paket
Name[en]=Verify Package
Name[es]=Verifique El Paquete
Name[fr]=Vérifier l'emballage
Name[it]=Verifichi Il Pacchetto
Name[nl]=Pakket Controleren

[Desktop Action Apkg-Remove]
Exec=/usr/libexec/autopackage/autosu-gtk --root-only package remove sylteditor
Icon=package
Name=Remove Package
Name[de]=Entfernen Paket
Name[en]=Remove Package
Name[es]=Quite El Paquete
Name[fr]=Enlevez Le Paquet
Name[it]=Rimuova Il Pacchetto
Name[nl]=Pakket Verwijderen
```

Comment: Answer added, give me a ping if you have any  further problems.

Comment: start the installation again in a terminal and paste the output into your question. To do that, go in the folder where you have extracted  `sylteditor-1.1.5108.tar.gz`, start the command `script` and after that `./SYLT\ Editor\ 1.1.5108.package`. After the installation, stop the `script` command via Ctrl-D and post the content of the file `typescript`

Comment: @A.B. Updated the question

Comment: And the Desktop files?

Comment: @A.B. They still do not exist.

Comment: @A.B. The following file exists though: /usr/local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop

Comment: Oh, I forgot the `/usr/local/share`

Comment: Start the app via `/opt/sylteditor/bin/sylteditor` and check the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install via

```
cd
wget http://www.compuphase.com/software/sylteditor-1.1.5108.tar.gz
tar xf sylteditor-1.1.5108.tar.gz
./SYLT\ Editor\ 1.1.5108.package
```

after the installation is finished, the desktop file is in

```
~/.local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop
```

or

```
/usr/local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop
```

or

```
/usr/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop
```

depending on your installation method (with `sudo` password or without).

---

To show the executable, run the command below

```
grep 'Exec.*/bin/sylt' ~/.local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop
```

or

```
grep 'Exec.*/bin/sylt' /usr/local/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop
```

or

```
grep 'Exec.*/bin/sylt' /usr/share/applications/sylteditor.desktop
```

---

SYLT editor is a 32-bit application. Therefore you have to install some i386 libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libwxbase2.8-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media2.8-0:i386
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I finally got to run it. The problem though is that it alarms with this error at startup: "Could not find a suitable video sink (error 0: Success)". And fails to open any audio file.

Comment: That could be a new question…